# Best way to insert different lines of text from one file into a particular line into a group of files

Tags: bash, perl, sed, scripting

Here's what I have.

File with data:

```
5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et pri sumo facer, in duo putant atomorum. Usu moderatius
ullamcorper eu, at pri modus summo necessitatibus, pro illum urbanitas ut. Qui cu falli
gloriatur, at perpetua tincidunt nec, vis an lorem detraxit. Audiam insolens nam cu, dico suas
mel eu, pro an doctus habemus mandamus.

6 Assum tibique eloquentiam ne mei, at mel quando tamquam iudicabit. In adhuc everti vix, no
hendrerit persecuti cum. Latine lucilius id sit, an mei maiestatis instructior. Id duo sint
vidit perfecto. Affert adipisci urbanitas ne sit, cu oblique appareat efficiendi cum, mel munere
utamur ad. An eum eius dicam, mei malis vocent epicurei cu, an his appareat insolens constituto.

7 Ut eum falli reprehendunt. Te mea homero expetendis. Ullum numquam accumsan te nam, quo eu
diceret sadipscing. Eam eu erant consulatu assentior. Sed ei quem munere docendi, te accusam
delectus vel.

8 Facete vivendo qui no, reque dolore repudiare ad qui. Sit ea tation iisque delenit. Ad quod
brute usu, ei alii semper iracundia sit. Ius atqui aperiam eu, nec no minimum deleniti. Putent
dolorem vulputate eu nec, sit nihil facilis complectitur te.

9 Per brute assueverit at. Ut vim labitur debitis, nec alii nonumes oporteat no. Usu ea animal
blandit corrumpit. Ei alterum praesent vis, pro idque saepe vocent an. Usu in accusata invenire
iracundia, graeco officiis vim eu.
```

And I have a bunch of files with a blank line 13 in each of them:

- 2020-10-12-lorem.md
- 2020-10-13-ipsum.md
- 2020-10-14-dolor.md
- 2020-10-15-sit.md
- 2020-10-16-amet.md

Is there a way to insert the first paragraph including the starting numeral into line 13 of the  first file, 2nd paragraph into line 13 of the 2nd file, etc..

For example:

2020-10-12-lorem.md

```
5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et pri sumo facer, in duo putant atomorum. Usu moderatius
ullamcorper eu, at pri modus summo necessitatibus, pro illum urbanitas ut. Qui cu falli
gloriatur, at perpetua tincidunt nec, vis an lorem detraxit. Audiam insolens nam cu, dico suas
mel eu, pro an doctus habemus mandamus.
```

2020-10-13-ipsum.md

```
6 Assum tibique eloquentiam ne mei, at mel quando tamquam iudicabit. In adhuc everti vix, no
hendrerit persecuti cum. Latine lucilius id sit, an mei maiestatis instructior. Id duo sint
vidit perfecto. Affert adipisci urbanitas ne sit, cu oblique appareat efficiendi cum, mel munere
utamur ad. An eum eius dicam, mei malis vocent epicurei cu, an his appareat insolens constituto
```

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes". What have you tried so far and how did it fail?

Comment: I think  you can reduce your sample case so it is easier to test. Please read [mcve] and more particulararly the section 'How to turn a bad script into a good question' in [bash tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#Input file
my $filewithdata = "FileWithData.txt"; my $temp;

#Input file reading here
open(FILE, $filewithdata) || die "... $!\n";
{ local $/; $_ = <FILE>; $temp = $_;  }
close(FILE);


#List of Blank data files
my @Tobe_Inserted_files = qw(2020-10-12-lorem.md 2020-10-13-ipsum.md 2020-10-14-dolor.md 2020-10-15-sit.md 2020-10-16-amet.md );

#Split the data file by double entermark (As per your example)
my @datasSplited = split /\n{2,}/, $temp; my $i = 0;
for(@datasSplited)
{
    #Each splitted data into the corresponding files
    open(OUT, ">$Tobe_Inserted_files[$i]") || die "...$!\n";
    print OUT $_;
    close(OUT);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Some feedback on your code. You should use 3-argument open with explicit open mode to avoid code injection. You should use lexical filehandles, i.e. `my $fh`. In your `die` statement, you should not end it with a newline (because then it does not show the line number in the error message). The idiomatic way to slurp a file into a variable is `my $file = do { local $/; <file> };`.

Comment: As for solution, I believe I would not slurp the file, but instead read line-by-line and using the input record separator in paragraph mode. `$/ = ''`. Look it up if you like.

Comment: The question was how to insert a line at line number 13, by the way, not how to overwrite existing files with lines from the input file. I believe a simple solution might be to use `Tie::File`.

Comment: Yes I accepted that 3-argument to enhance in the code. Thanks for your update.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU csplit & parallel):

```
csplit  dataFile '/^$/1' '{*}' &&
parallel sed -i -e \''13r {1}'\' -e \''13d'\' {2} ::: xx?? :::+ fileMD{1..3} &&
rm xx??
```

Split the data file into separate files named xx00, xx01, ...

Pair each xxnn file with its counterpart markdown file, inserting the paragraph at line 13, deleting the existing line 13.

Finally, remove the split files.